# How to do a deep copy of a scope into a new one that doesn't track the changes of the original scope?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular JS and I have two scopes

```
$scope.selected = {
    ids: []
};

$scope.copy = {
    ids: []
};
```

when I click a button I want `$scope.copy` to get the elements from `$scope.selected` so I did this

```
<button ng-click="copy=selected">copy</button>
```

this works in part but now each time I change the values of selected, the values of copy change too.
I've also tried using a function but it didn't solve my problem.

```
$scope.copylist = function(selected) {
    $scope.copy.ids.push(selected.ids.valueOf());
}
```

How would I make a copy that doesn't update when the values from the original scope are updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) should do the trick

```
<button ng-click="copyScope()">copy</button>

function copyScope () {
    $scope.copy = angular.copy($scope.selected);
}
```

**Code Explanation**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="copyOriginal()">copyOriginal</button>
    <button ng-click="touchOriginal()">touchOriginal</button>
    <pre> {{original}} </pre>
    <pre> {{copy}} </pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.original = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.copy = [];

$scope.touchOriginal = function () {
    $scope.original.push(4);
};

$scope.copyOriginal = function () {
    $scope.copy = angular.copy($scope.original);
    console.log($scope.copy);
}

$scope.$watch('copy', function (newCopy, oldCopy) {
    // Nothing should happen here when you trigger `touchOriginal()`
    console.log(newCopy, oldCopy);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/g54401m2/)**